# Why is my save(validate:false) command causing a stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, recursion, stack-overflow, circular-reference

I would love to understand recursiveness and what I've done to create a circular reference.

```
class SomeModel 
  # callback to calculate something only if the status_id has been changed
  after_save :calculate_something if: :status_id_changed?

  def calculate_something
    # this unless combined with the callback if means this is only run if not only the status_id has been changed, but that it's been changed to a non-nil value
    unless self.status_id.nil?
      self.run_first_calculation
    end
  end

  def run_first_calculation
    self.save(validate:false)
  end
end
```

I'm getting a `stack level too deep` error because of the `self.save(validate:false)`. But I'm not sure why because saving with a validation false does not change the `status_id`, but when I have a regular `self.save`, it's fine.

If you take the above, and run in the console:

```
some_model_instance.update_attribute(:status_id, 2)
# => stack level too deep
```

I don't get why. Here's what I think is happening:

1. `some_model_instance` gets an updated `status_id`
2. because of that, the callback runs (now we're in `run_calculations`)
3. because the `status_id` is not nil, we are inside the `unless` block
4. the `run_first_calculation` method is called
5. we save `some_model_instance` arbitrarily
6. but because the `status_id` is not changed, we shouldn't run into the callback again

Comment: Since you wrote a regular save does not cause the problem, is there any validation callbacks? Also, what are the values of status_id and status_id_was in the second calculate_something call?

Comment: Validation callbacks are really basic presence checks and format checks, nothing complex that would cause this, especially since false just skips them, right? Status_id is  updated appropriately (i.e., it is 2)

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs into an `stack level too deep` exception, because `status_id_changed?` still returns `true` in an `after_save` callback.

`after_save` callbacks run in the same transaction then the original `save`. Is is done to allow to rollback the after save changes together with the original changes if something goes wrong. But the dirty attribute flags are resetted after the transaction is finished.

That said your second `save` in `run_first_calculation` just triggers the same callback again with `status_id_changed?` still being `true`.

Comment: Oh interesting. Any idea why removing `validate:false` fixes the problem? And if I understand the order of call backs correctly, it seems like an `after_update` might fix this right?